# Azure Cosmos DB Mongo API Stored Procedure

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I need to write where condition for  Azure Cosmos DB Mongo API DB 
I have written sp to get all data but when i add where condition it's not returning data.

I need help on writing SP in Mongo API with return as same json what i saved or new json with selected properties

```
function sample(prefix) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();
var filterQuery2 = 'SELECT * FROM root r where r.userName= "' + prefix + '"';
    // Query documents and take 1st item.
    var isAccepted = collection.queryDocuments(
        collection.getSelfLink(),
        filterQuery2,
    function (err, feed, options) {
        if (err) throw err;

        // Check the feed and if empty, set the body to 'no docs found', 
        // else take 1st element from feed
        if (!feed || !feed.length) {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            response.setBody('no docs found');
        }
        else {
            var response = getContext().getResponse();
            var body = { prefix: prefix, feed: feed[0] };
            response.setBody(JSON.stringify(body));
        }
    });

    if (!isAccepted) throw new Error('The query was not accepted by the server.');
}
```

Comment: Not quite sure I understand the question, but... Cosmos DB's stored procedures are callable from the Core (SQL) API, not the MongoDB API.

Comment: If i do this will it be getting the matched one or will get all records from DB and then filter by user name ? var collection = GetTasksCollection(); return collection.Find(x=>x.abc==userName).SortByDescending(i=>i.CreatedDate).FirstOrDefault();

Answer (score 0):

I tested cosmos db mongo api stored procedure, as same as you.

[image]

Your normal format of json document was converted into `$v and $t`, that's why your filter malfunctioned.

You could see the same situation in this [thread](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/5460) and this [case](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e0ffdbcd-0b43-4cd5-9d21-1a95ce0279dd/mongodb-contains-v-and-t-in-query-result?forum=azurecosmosdb) , cosmos db team made an official statement:

> The incorrect format is a result of intermixing the Cosmos DB: MongoDB
>   API with the Cosmos DB: DocumentDB API.

I suggest you trying to contact with azure team or commit feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db).

Comment: for me where condition is also not returning the data .. the only way for now is reading data from collection from code that will be big performance issue so..fingers crossed

Comment: If i do this will it be getting the matched one or will get all reacords from DB and then filter by user name ?  var collection = GetTasksCollection();
                return collection.Find(x=>x.abc==userName).SortByDescending(i=>i.CreatedDate).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: 1) As I stated in comments above (and as @Jay has pointed out here) - this is not a valid use of Cosmos DB stored procedures. 2) why would you have a big performance hit? 3) Please don't ask additional questions in comments (and remember - you should not be applying Cosmos DB stored procedures to MongoDB API data).